# Scrapy error pulling up Selector

Tags: python, html, xml, scrapy, python-requests

I am using a list of 335 URLs each made from a different gene access number to make requests from the NCBI website GenBank. The part of the data I want is in an XPath called:

```
//*[@id="viewercontent1"]/pre
```

I can't seem to pull up what selector tool thing I need to get it, and I need a small excerpt of texts from each XML page on GenBank.

My code is:

```
import csv

result = []
for line in open("C:/Projects/NCBI Scraper project/geneAccNumbers.txt"):
    result.append(line.split(','))


csv = open("C:/Projects/NCBI Scraper project/geneAccNumbers.txt", 'r')
for gene in csv.readline().split(','):
URL = URL = 'https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/' + gene + '.1?report=fasta'

def build_url(gene):
return 'https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/' + gene + '.1?report=fasta'

genes_urls = [build_url(gene) for gene in csv]

import pip
import requests

res = []
for url in genes_urls:
res.append(requests.get(url))


import scrapy

hxs.select('//*[@id="viewercontent1"]/pre').extract()
```

Everything ran except that last line. I also need to know ways to split up and organize all the scraped text data I want.

This is an example the website of the information I want to scrape:

https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/DQ147858.1?report=fasta

Any help very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You don't really need `scrapy` here. You only need a part of it, called `parsel` which will be used for parsing the response (you can use `beautifulsoup` or whatever HTML parsing lib you like).

But here's one more thing: the data you want is added by JavaScript code, which means that it is not present on the response from the URL you requesting. So you will need to make an extra request to their API ([link](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/sviewer/viewer.fcgi?id=74134028&db=nuccore&report=fasta&extrafeat=null&conwithfeat=on&retmode=html&withmarkup=on&tool=portal&log$=seqview&maxdownloadsize=1000000)) to get the data you want. As you can see, this link returns exactly what you need.

But if you look closely at the URL params, you'll notice the `id`, which we do not have. But it can be easily parsed from the first response.

So the code will look like this:

```
import parsel
import requests

# URL of the data you want
detail_url_template = (
    'https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/sviewer/viewer.fcgi'
    '?id={id}'
    '&db=nuccore'
    '&report=fasta'
    '&extrafeat=null'
    '&conwithfeat=on'
    '&retmode=html'
    '&withmarkup=on'
    '&tool=portal'
    '&log$=seqview'
    '&maxdownloadsize=1000000'
)

data = []
for url in genes_urls:
    # Get the response from the gene URL
    response = requests.get(url)
    s = parsel.Selector(response.text)

    # Extract id value for future request
    val = s.css('#viewercontent1::attr(val)').extract_first()  

    # Get the URL where the data you want is located
    detail_url = detail_url_template.format(id=val)

    response = requests.get(detail_url)
    data.append(response.text)
```